# Infopath cannot open file : Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have been trying to Programmatially open a Infopath (2013) from from a SharePoint list (2013) in order to call the print to PDF functionality of the infopath client application.

When trying to open the Infopath file I am receiving the following error:
InfoPath cannot open the following file: {sharepoint filename}.xml. Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

My C# code looks something like this:

```
string fileName = string.Format(@"{0}/{1}", application.Web.Url, application.Url);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application infoPathApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.Application();
XDocument InfXDoc = infoPathApp.XDocuments.Open(fileName, (int)XdDocumentVersionMode.xdCanOpenInReadOnlyMode);
```

Any ideas what would be causing this error?

thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue and believe we have found the cause. Check your IE browser settings and verify that "Do Not Save Encrypted Files to Disk" is not checked. If it is checked it will trigger this error message.

Comment: After trying several other things, this actually worked for me.

Comment: Wasn't checked to begin with, yet getting the error.